# Android: listview pushed up when contextual actionbar is shown

Tags: android, listview, contextual-action-bar

I have a listview with checkbox to select a row. Also I have a contextual action bar that pops up when an item is selected. My issue is that whenever I select an item , the list is pushed up and I see only the last items. If I have selected the first few items that were initially visible , those will be pushed up and can be seen only after scrolling down.This happens only for the first time when CAB is launched. If i select a second item the listview desnt scroll up or down as CAB is already visible and is not launched again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my layout , for listview the following was set.
 android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"

I removed this and it works now